# Haml in Maruku Filter

Tags: ruby, haml, maruku

For this project, I need to be able to mix Haml tags within the Maruku filter. For example, will I be able to do this:

```
#contain
  :maruku
    ## Hello H2 Tag
      div{:id => 'divinmaruku'}
        **Can I do this?**
```

I know you can just unindent where you want to get out Maruku, but it is a pain to do `:maruku` whenever I want to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do this (at least, not without hacking Maruku so that it calls out to Haml). You can insert literal HTML, or use Maruku's div syntax:

```
+-----------{#divinmaruku}---
| **You can do this**
+----------------------------
```

This renders as

```
<div id='divinmaruku'>
<p><strong>You can do this</strong></p>
</div>
```